# Vim doesn't show plugin documentation

Tags: vim, vim-plugins

When I put a symbolic link to a .txt documentation plugin, vim doesn't show me the help

Example: 
I have in ~/.vim/doc

```
 $ ls -al NERD_tree.txt 
 NERD_tree.txt -> PATH/nerdtree/doc/NERD_tree.txt
```

in vim:

```
:h NERDtree
```

This command doesn't show the documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vim needs to know when the help files are updated, so it can know where the `NERDtree` tag should point.  Running the following in vim should fix it:

```
:helptags ~/.vim/doc
```